# Steam RSA encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa, steam

I am working on a steam web library and i have tried to rebuild the web login. It consists of two steps:
Getting the RSA keys and posting the encrypted password to the servers. But approx. since two weeks i am can't get the encryption to work.

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters {
    Exponent = encryptPasswordModel.PublicKeyExp.HexToByte(),
    Modulus = encryptPasswordModel.PublicKeyMod.HexToByte()
};
rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
var bytePassword = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptPasswordModel.Password);
var encodedPassword = rsa.Encrypt(bytePassword, false);
return Convert.ToBase64String(encodedPassword);
```

This has worked fine but i believe the implementation of the Steam rsa encryption have changed at some point. Currently the encryption can be found [here](https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/shared/javascript/crypto/rsa.js). Steam is also using a package called jsbn.js. It can be found [here](https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/shared/javascript/crypto/jsbn.js).

```
encrypt: function($data, $pubkey) {
  if (!$pubkey) return false;
  $data = this.pkcs1pad2($data, ($pubkey.modulus.bitLength() + 7) >> 3);
  if (!$data) return false;
  $data = $data.modPowInt($pubkey.encryptionExponent, $pubkey.modulus);
  if (!$data) return false;
  $data = $data.toString(16);
  if (($data.length & 1) == 1)
    $data = "0" + $data;
  return Base64.encode(Hex.decode($data));
}

pkcs1pad2: function($data, $keysize) {
  if ($keysize < $data.length + 11)
    return null;
  var $buffer = [];
  var $i = $data.length - 1;
  while ($i >= 0 && $keysize > 0)
    $buffer[--$keysize] = $data.charCodeAt($i--);
  $buffer[--$keysize] = 0;
  while ($keysize > 2)
    $buffer[--$keysize] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 254) + 1;
  $buffer[--$keysize] = 2;
  $buffer[--$keysize] = 0;
  return new BigInteger($buffer);
}
```

As we can see we have something like a custom encryption padding which is called 'pkcs1pad2'. How can i implement this in the same way in C# without that much trouble (best solution would be .net core solution but it is not necessary).

I tried it already with `RSA.Create();` but was not successful with it yet.

```
var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters {
    Exponent = encryptPasswordModel.PublicKeyExp.HexToByte(),
    Modulus = encryptPasswordModel.PublicKeyMod.HexToByte()
};
var rsa2 = RSA.Create();
rsa2.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
var byteEncodedPassword = rsa2.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptPasswordModel.Password), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
var encryptedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(byteEncodedPassword);
```

I think this has not worked out yet because of the padding but how am i able to extend the algorithm of the `RSAEncryptionPadding`.

Answer (score 0):

`pkcs1pad2` looks like it builds the following data (from back to front):

```
0x00 0x02 [a series of non-zero random bytes] 0x00 [data]
```

This is exactly the PKCS#1 v1.5 encryption padding algorithm (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7.2.1), which is what .NET calls `RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1` (and is what you get from `RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt` when passing `false` to `fOAEP`).

If things stopped working suddenly this really suggests one of

- The key to use has changed.
- The password you're sending has changed.

with an additional candidate of

- The things you are supposed to do to the password before encryption have changed.

#### On extending RSAEncryptionPadding

The types in .NET don't actually do RSA, they defer to system libraries which can do RSA for them, and that includes the padding. So it's not a polymorphic structure that you can just make a new one of and pass around. If you wanted to make up your own padding you'd need to define your own subclass of `RSA` and then make a non-standard addition to the padding options.

aka it's a lot of work, it's hard to do securely (timing problems in RSA decryption), and you should be happy here that you don't need to do it, since the padding algorithm isn't the problem you're having.

Comment: The key to use is changing every hour. I was updating it accordingly (i double checked this always). The password has not changed either.

I have found another example of the RSA encryption used which you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/igeligel/0ef908b236f3621a5dbb23941bad107e) now.